# positive integer $n$ in definite integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Find the positive integer $n$ such that $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}x^n \sin xdx = \frac{3}{4}(\pi^2-8).$

Try: $$ I_{n} = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}x^n \sin xdx =-x^n\cos x\bigg|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}+n\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}x^{n-1}\cos x dx$$

$$I_{n} = nx^{n-1}\sin x\bigg|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}-n(n-1)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}x^{n-2}\sin xdx$$

could some help me to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [reduction formula (sec 5.3.3 (a))](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4zO5CL71q24C&pg=PA335&dq=reduction+formula+for+x%5En+sinx&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl-sX0sc_YAhUJto8KHeMRBpMQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=reduction%20formula%20for%20x%5En%20sinx&f=false) for the integral, we have: $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin x \, dx = \left[-x^n \cos x + nx^{n-1} \sin x \right] \bigg \lvert_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - n(n-1)I_{n-2}$$ $$ = n\left(\frac{\pi} {2} \right)^{n-1} - n(n-1)I_{n-2}$$

We can easily see that $n=3$ is the answer, which can also be verified by calculating $I_1$ also.

Answer (score 1):

$I_{3}=3\cdot\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{4}-6\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\sin xdx=\dfrac{3\pi^{2}}{4}-6\left(-x\cos x\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\pi/2}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos xdx\right)=\dfrac{3\pi^{2}}{4}-6$.